# Check records existance in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

my question is regarding the existance of records in a table. How could i get a resulting list which really notifies if the record i'm looking for des or does not exist ?
I mean, i know i can check for what does exist with a query like

```
SELECT field FROM table WHERE unique_field IN (value1, value2)
```

And that will show me those record wich actually exist. But what if i want a result like:

```
+--------------+-------+
| unique_field | exists|
+--------------+-------+
| value1       | 1     |
| value2       | 0     |
+--------------+-------+
```

Is it possible to do so ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `EXISTS()`, it stops searching for more rows when there's a hit, so you won't have much overhead when searching big tables.

```
SELECT 'value1' AS unique_field, EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM your_table WHERE unique_field = 'value1') AS 'exists'
UNION ALL 
SELECT 'value2' AS unique_field, EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM your_table WHERE unique_field = 'value2') AS 'exists'
```

Comment: You're right, default sql mode in mysql is "" though, as long as sql mode "ignore space" is not set, this still works. Thanks for your suggestion, though.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this using a "reference" table for the values:

```
select ref.val,
       (exists (select 1 from table t where t.unique_field = ref.val)) as `exists`
from (select 'value1' as val union all
      select 'value2' as val
     ) ref;
```

You can also phrase this as a `left outer join`:

```
select ref.val,
       (t.unique_field is not null) as `exists`
from (select 'value1' as val union all
      select 'value2' as val
     ) ref left outer join
     table t
     on t.unique_field = ref.val;
```

This works because the field in `table` is unique (otherwise, you might get duplicate rows or need aggregation).

Comment: I like this one, it utilises the fact that MySQL deals with a left join much better than it does with subqueries.

Answer (score 0):

check `count(*)` to get the no of  record and if it `returns 0` then there is no record exists

in the table.

```
SELECT count(*) FROM table WHERE unique_field IN (value1, value2);
```

Answer (score 0):

not as nice as you could hope, but

```
select '1', exists(select null from t1 where val = 1) 'exists'
union
select '2', exists(select null from t1 where val = 2)
```

or

```
SELECT 
id as unique_field, exists(select null from t1 where val = id) as 'exists'
FROM (
  SELECT 1 as id
  union 
  SELECT 2
  union
  select 3
  union
  select 4
) q;
```

see [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/017849/12)